# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline - How to Automate Registration of Deployment Group targets

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Currently the Deployment Group 'Register' script needs to be run interactively by providing information like tags, Token, account credentials etc.

It becomes a tedious task to run this interactive script on hundreds of machines to register them into Azure Pipeline Deployment Group.

Is there a way, where we can run in non-interactive mode by passing the required information as a parameter to script?

For e.g. .\scriptToAddToDeploymentGroup.ps1 <--tags appServer, domainController, etc> <--token 43875783457834545>

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?Your idea is achievable.You can add tags, tokens as parameters to the Registration script. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hugh, Thanks I just saw that you have sent latest response on this. Since it was editied, probably i didnt receive notification. I will try this and let you know. Its a great help, Highly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi,Pratik. If this answer is helpful to you ,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

> Can we automate this task from command line by passing parameter
>   values?

For this issue , the answer is yes.
You could add tags and token as parameters to the Registration script. For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#authentication-options).

If you chose `--auth pat`:
`--token <token>` - specifies your personal access token

`--deploymentGroupTags <tags>` - used with `--addDeploymentGroupTags` to specify the comma separated list of tags for the deployment group agent - for example "web, db"

For example:

```
\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "xxx" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://dev.azure.com/xx/' --projectname 'xxx'
```

Comment: Thank you, but am curious to know why the query has been voted down? The reason I asked this question is to automate the registration process on hundreds of machines as it is tedious to logon to each machine. This can be achieved in Octopus agent registration but wanted to know if anyone has similar solution in Azure DevOps

Comment: Need to clarify that I did not vote down your question .The person who voted down may not understand your question. I think what you are asking is a practical question. Your idea is achievable.You can add tags, tokens as parameters to the Registration script.

Comment: Can we also pass the tags along with other values?

Comment: The parameters listed in the document should be passable